# SWT List should overlay other elements

Tags: java, list, swt, overlay

i want that the list ist right under the textbox. So there should be no space between the list and the textbox. And the list should overlay all following elements.

The code:

```
_txtDescription = new Text(grpOptions, SWT.BORDER);
        gridData = new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL
                | GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_FILL);
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
        gridData.verticalSpan = 3;

        gridData.heightHint = 12;
        gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;

        _txtDescription.setLayoutData(gridData);
        _txtDescription.setTextLimit(40);

        myList2 = new List(grpOptions, SWT.BORDER);
gridData = new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL
                | GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING);
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;

        gridData.heightHint = 80;
        gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;

        myList2.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

Any ways to get this working?

Comment: Do you want to implement [something like this](http://static.cubiq.org/uploads/2009/03/Spinning-Wheel-slot-machine-alike.jpeg)?

Comment: Or do you want [something like this](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/assets/autocomplete/img/autocomplete-01.png)?

Comment: @Baz something like yours ;)

Comment: There is a whole lot of information about this, e.g. [here](http://krishnanmohan.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/eclipse-rcp-autocompletecombotext-control/), [here](http://bytes.com/topic/java/insights/879093-auto-completion-swt-text-field), [here](http://alexander.lds.lg.ua/2010/09/auto-completion-in-swt-text-field/)...